# How to resolve Haskell type errors

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I'm trying to learn Haskell, and I'm writing the unzip function (yes I know it's built in, this is practice) but I'm having issues with my recursion line. I have:

```
-- unzip turns a list of two element tuples into two lists
unzip' [] = ([],[])
unzip' [(x,y):ls] = 
    let 
        (a, b) = unzip' ls
    in
        ([x] ++ a, [y] ++ b)
```

But I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(t, t1)'
           against inferred type `[(t, t1)]'
      Expected type: [(t, t1)] -> (t2, t3)
      Inferred type: [[(t, t1)]] -> ([a], [a1])
    In the expression: unzip' ls
    In a pattern binding: (a, b) = unzip' ls
```

I don't understand how to unpack the results of the recursive call. Can anyone explain how to unpack the two lists from the returned tuple?

Comment: Just a side note: You can always write  `e:es` instead of `[e] ++ es` this is much cheaper (1 constructor call) vs. 1 constructor calls and a not so cheap function call. Even if that nanosecond does not matter, the first form is much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i don't know if this solves it but it looks to me that

```
unzip' [(x,y):ls] =
```

should just be:

```
unzip' ((x,y):ls) =
```

Comment: That's exactly it: `[(x,y):ls]` matches a one-element list whose only element is a list of pairs.

Comment: Wow I'm dumb, those were supposed to be parentheses. I never would've figured that out, thanks a ton.

Comment: Using `Control.Applicative` you have the beautiful `unzip' = (,) <$> map fst <*> map snd`

Comment: @Landei: Or, using `Control.Arrow`, `unzip' = map fst &&& map snd`.

Comment: @hammar: That's what I love when writing Haskell: If you think you have the "perfect" solution, there is always a better one :-)